# How to replace page with a component

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Let's say we have a blog page with a div class of content and there are previews of articles.

What I want to do is to replace div class of content with the specific article. How can I achieve this?

```js
function Blog() {
    redirectToArticle(id) = () => {
       title = getTitle(id)
       content = getContent(id)
       {/*## code to replace div 'content' with <Article title={title} content={content}/>*/}
   } 

   return(
   <div className="content">
    <div onClick={redirectToArticle(1)}>
        <h1>Article Title 1</h1>
        <p>Short preview from the article here...</p>
    </div>
   </div>
   )
}
```

Article example:

```js
class Article extends React.Component {
    constructor(props) {
      super(props);
      this.state = { title: 'Title', content: 'Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.. . .. . . . . . . . . .'};
    }
    
  render(){
    return(
    <>
    <h1>{this.title}</h1>
    <p>{this.content}</p>
    </>
    )
  }
  
  }
```

Comment: Change state and let it re-render.  This is the way.

Comment: But how do I replace contents  of <div className="content"> with <Article /> ?

Comment: if (youWantToRenderTheDiv) return <div ...> else return <Article/>

Answer (score 0):

Why would you like to replace that div? Isn't it better to display the thumbnail with the basic information + onClick route to the main article?
I highly recommend using NextJS for that one - static props will help you a lot with that and will ensure you have a good structure - but with a simple CRA you can do it as well. Display a thumbnail with a short description and add onClick a page of the article with all the details and passed props.

Comment: I'm not a fan of answers that ask questions.  Ask your questions for clarification in a comment on the original question.  Answer the question when you're confident it's aligned with the asker's intent.

Comment: I don't want to use routers because I already have one and can't put one more router.